# composition relationship with abstract class

Tags: class, uml, relationship, abstract, composition

Is it possible that there will be a composition relationship with ِAbstract class using UML? I think we can't, because we need an object to make this relation, and when we create an abstract class, we can't create an object from it.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to Programmers.SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, and it is often useful. Look at this example :

[UML composition abstract http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/compositionAbstract.jpg](http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/compositionAbstract.jpg)

*Building* and *Room* are abstract and have a composition relationship.
But you are right, you will need to use one concrete class (House or Flat) to implement this relationship.

Comment: Thank you ... if there is any reference(e-book), could you please post it here